# Android: Spinner from ID Is Always Null

Tags: android, android-activity, null, spinner, fragment

I have a fragment and an activity. The activity inflates the fragment. The xml file of the fragment contains the @+id for the spinner.

In the onCreate of the activity, I'm trying to get the spinner from the fragment.

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
```

mySpinner is consistently coming back as null. I'm absolutely sure the ID is correct.

How do I fix this?

EDIT:
Here is the full onCreate of the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newtimer);

    myArray = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myspinner);

    db = new DBAdapter(this);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Bundle type = getIntent().getExtras();

    String stringType = type.getString("type");

    if (stringType.equals(A_STRING_HERE))
    {
        MyCustomFragment myFragment = new MyCustomFragment();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, myFragment); // fragmentContainer is a FrameLayout that I use to swap with fragments
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();


        //TODO Load active timers
        db.open();

        Cursor myCursor = db.getEntry(0);
        if(myCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            String curr = myCursor.getString(2);
            Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myspinner;
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.myspinner,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            if (myspinnerr == null)
            {
                Log.d("NewTimerActivity", "spinner is null!");
            }
            myspinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            int i = java.util.Arrays.asList(myArray).indexOf(curr);
            myspinner.setSelection(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is your `setContentView` call above the quoted line?

Comment: Yes, I've already checked for that. What I'm doing is setting the content view to a basic LinearLayout xml file that contains a FrameLayout. The FrameLayout is then replaced with a fragment from another file (the same fragment that contains the spinner). And of course, all of that is called before the quoted line.

Answer (score 1):

You should have this in your `Fragment`, not your `Activity`.

Try something like

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
```

in your `Fragment`. The reason is that it's your fragment that actually has the view, not the activity.

EDIT based on your onCreate:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)myFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
```

Comment: The onClick for a button in the fragment gets put in the activity class. I can successfully call "Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_herbs0);" in this onClick method within the activity.

Comment: But I still need to do so in the onCreate of the activity.

Comment: You need to wait until the fragment is fully inflated then. Post your whole onCreate please.

Comment: I have posted my onCreate as requested. Also, I tried it on an overridden onResume, and it works fine (spinner is not null). However, it's a bit sketchy and I would prefer to do it on onCreate if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Everything does work in the onResume, though. I might just have to do it there as that will get called anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

By default spinner will select one item inside it, so the position 0 of the spinner item should be disabled.